# Why doesn't G++ generate a warning for template methods not returning anything?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, warnings

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class C2 {
     public: 
             T method() { }
             int method2() { }
};
```

Compiling it with `g++ -Wall -c -pedantic` gives me the following warning:

`test.cpp: In member function ‘int C2<T>::method2()’:`
`test.cpp:4:29: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]`

Which is expected. The strange thing is that `method()` isn't returning anything either. Why doesn't that generate a warning, since instantiating `C2` with `T = int` makes calls to both methods equally dangerous?

Comment: Are you instantiating `C2` somewhere when compiling?

Comment: [Works here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3ea9d586eb0ce16cff833f15be02b0e7).

Comment: Did you actually call "method"? The compiler does not generate code for template functions that are not exercised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you say `T = void`, then no `return` statement is needed.

Just because you *can* use your template in a way that's broken doesn't mean you *have* to, and the com­piler may be giving you the benefit of the doubt.

Also remember that member functions of a class template are *only instantiated if and when used*. So the way to actually *cause* an error is to have `C2<char> x; x.method();`, and that does indeed produce a warning.

Comment: Makes sense: the compiler can't say it does or does not return void if it's not instantiated. Also, only instantiating the template doesn't give a warning, but calling the method indeed does, just as you said. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the function isn't generated *even if it doesn't have the template variable return type*. So, if you don't call `x.method2()`, it won't generate the warning from the original question. (Just realized that myself)

Comment: Hmm. Here, I use g++ 4.7.0, and it generates that warning for `method2` even if I don't call it (the code I tested was exactly what I posted, with nothing added).

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to call "method" in order for the compiler to compile it. It's a template function after all. See comment in code below.

```
template <typename T>
class C2 {
     public: 
             T method() { }
             int method2() { }
};

int main()
{
   C2<int> c;
   c.method2();
   // If you comment out the below line, there is no warning printed.
   c.method();
}
```